# Proving inequality $\int_a^{\pi/2}\cos^nxdx\le e^{-na^2/2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^nxdx$

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality, definite-integrals

> How to prove $$\int_a^{\pi/2}\cos^nxdx\le e^{-na^2/2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^nxdx,$$
>   where $n\in\mathbb N$ and $a\in[0,\pi/2]$?

I noticed that if we can prove
$$\cos^na\le nae^{-na^2/2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^nxdx,$$
apply $\displaystyle\int_a^{\pi/2}$ to both side, the conclusion will follow. But unfortunately, this inequality above is not true. When $a=0$, $LHS=1>0=RHS$. Also, Wallis' formula can help us find $\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^nxdx$. I'm not sure if it helps.

Comment: It may help to note that $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(x)^a\cos(x)^bdx=\frac12\text{B}\bigg(\frac{a+1}2,\frac{b+1}2\bigg)$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $0\leq x\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $0\leq a\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$. Then we can see
$$
\cos(x+a) = \cos x\cos a-\sin x\sin a\leq \cos a\cos x.
$$
Let $$
f(t) = -\frac{t^2}{2} -\ln (\cos t), \quad 0\leq t<\frac{\pi}{2}.
$$
Then, $f(0) = 0$ and
$$
f'(t) = -t +\tan t\geq 0.
$$ Thus we have
$$
f(a) \geq 0,
$$and
$$
\cos a \leq e^{\frac{-a^2}{2}}.
$$ This implies
$$
\cos^n(x+a) \leq e^{-\frac{na^2}{2}}\cos^n x
$$ and hence
$$
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}-a}\cos^n(x+a)\leq e^{-\frac{na^2}{2}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}-a}\cos^n x\leq e^{-\frac{na^2}{2}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^n x.
$$